# In powershell using imagemagick, how to convert image to a new path

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I want to convert the tif into jpg that is placed in C:\Data\

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -filter *.tif | %{ convert $_.FullName "C:\Data\$($_.FullName -Replace ".tif+$", ".jpg")" }
```

But it does not work.

However this works - it places the converted file in the same location as the original file

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -filter *.tif | %{ convert $_.FullName "$($_.FullName -Replace ".tif+$", ".jpg")" }
```

Answer (score 1):

you're messing up the destination path by concatting `C:\data` with `$_.FullName` 
try just the `$_.Name` property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $source -filter *.tif | %{ convert $_.FullName "C:\Data\$($_.Name -Replace ".tif+$", ".jpg")" }
```